# Why does solving $A^{\rm T}Ax = A^{\rm T}b$ yield a least squares approximation?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I was following a linear algebra course, and I came upon an example where a linear regression was done by solving $A^{\rm T}Ax = A^{\rm T}b$, where $Ax = b$ could not be solved because $b$ is not in the column space of $A$. So the formula $A^{\rm T}Ax = A^{\rm T}b$ is derived as the projection of $b$ onto the column space of $A$, and solved for as an approximation.

What I am confused about is where during this derivation this became a *least squared* approximation. How would I formulate the problem in a similar way (as a linear algebra problem), but minimize **linear distance instead?** (edited, from Euclidean distance which was improper use of terminology)

What I mean to ask is when fitting a line to a set of points, if I wanted to minimize the absolute error, not the squared error, how would I formulate the problem?

Comment: It is minimizing Euclidean distance. The points to remember is that $Ax=0$ means $x$ is orthogonal to every row of  $A$, hence to the whole row space. Changing to $A^T$ gives similar statement about column space. So the Nullspace of $A^T$ and the column space of $A$ are two subspaces that are orthogonal to each other. Now you can work out the connection.

Comment: $x=(A^{\rm T}A)^{-1} Ab$ is such that the distance $||b-Ax||_2$ is minimal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is minimizing least squares equivalent to finding the projection matrix $\hat{x}=A^Tb(A^TA)^{-1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900072/why-is-minimizing-least-squares-equivalent-to-finding-the-projection-matrix-ha)

Comment: Question edited. I meant to ask, how could I minimize the absolute error, not the squared error when fitting a line to a set of points for example?

Comment: What do you mean by "absolute error"?

Answer (score 2):

Given an approximate solution $x$ we can define the squared error in the approximation as $E(x) = \| A x - b \|^2 = (Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$.

Finding the $x$ that minimises this "error" us the least squares solution.

$E$ has gradient $\nabla E(x) = 2 A^T(Ax-b)$. Also $E$ has a minimum when $\nabla E = 0$. i.e. when $A^TAx-A^Tb = 0$ - which is exactly the condition you want.

Comment: @ccorn too right - fixed. I've been using $E = \frac{1}{2}\Delta^2$ too much lately...

Answer (score 1):

You can think it through a geometric way. b is certainly not in the column space, but since the left-null space is the orthogonal component of the column space. We can divide b into two parts: b= b(column part) +b(left-null part). since the multiplication of the transpose of A and b(left-null part) is 0 , we can get Ax=b(column part). And b(column part) is the projection from b to the column space, which is closest to b